# Docker container delete from Jenkins hangs

Tags: jenkins, containers, docker, freeze

I tried today to configure my nodes in Jenkins with with docker 1.3.1, and Jenkins docker plugin v0.8.

The docker containers started successfully from jenkins but jenkins rejected them as the there were some echos in my bashrc. 
I deleted these nodes manually from Docker server.

Now, I need to delete these  nodes from jenkins and I cannot delete them. The delete operation simply hangs.
Any change to Jenkins configuration also hangs.

Any suggestions please?

Note:
tried using

1. Groovy console to delete Docker nodes
2. Tried using delete option from Manage jenkins -> nodes
3. Tried using Jenkins-cli script to delete these nodes.

**Container logs**

```
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:

hudson.AbortException
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.verifyNoHeaderJunk(SSHLauncher.java:854)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$100(SSHLauncher.java:134)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:698)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:691)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
[11/05/14 15:54:55] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[11/05/14 15:54:55] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Since any change in the configuration cannot be performed, I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually removed elements from jenkins/config.xml and restarted jenkins